# Probabilistic Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma for arbitrary points

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, metric-embeddings

Consider the following standard formulation of the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma:

> Lemma (JL).
>   For any $0<\epsilon < 1$ and any integer $n$, let $k$ be a positive integer such that $k\geq C\cdot \epsilon^{-2}\log n$ (for some explicit constant $C$ which we omit here). Then, for any set $X$ of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, there is a linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ such that ***for all*** $u,v\in X$, it holds;
>
> $||u-v||^2(1-\epsilon) \leq ||f(u)- f(v)||^2 \leq ||u-v||^2(1+\epsilon)$.
>
> Moreover, $f$ can be found in randomized polynomial time.

Now, what can be said about probabilistic $(1+\epsilon)$ distortion of arbitrary vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$, that are not necessarily drawn from $X$ ?

In particular, suppose $X$ is fixed and $f$ is randomly computed as in JL, then we pick an arbitrary $z\in \mathbb{R}^d$ at random, with independent normally distributed coordinates, i.e. $z_i\sim N(0,1)$, not necessarily in $X$, and we look at the distortion between $z$ and $x$, for every $x\in X$: can we appropriately bound the probability to get $(1+\epsilon)$ distortion w.r.t. $z,x$ ?

I guess it is possible to appropriately bound, and then amplify, the probability $\delta$ that an arbitrary (random) $z\in \mathbb{R}^d$ will be distorted by at most $(1+\epsilon)$ relative error w.r.t $X$, as above. Is this guess true ?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Hi D., my question would be: how would one treat arbitrary vectors ? Is the guess true ?

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I read what you already wrote, but it is not clear what you are asking. Consider rephrasing the question.

Comment: I tried rephrasing. Hope this clarify. If not, what is more  obscure?

Comment: Let $f$ be a random projection. Then it will be JL with high probability, regardless of $X$. If I make $X$ a little larger (by including $z$), $f$ will still be JL with high probability. Is this useful to you, or do you want to fix $f$ and only use the randomness in $z$?

Comment: I want to fix $f$, eventually compute $f$ w.r.t. to $X$ but then fix $f$. At this point use the randomness in $z$. Also consider that, for the fixed $f$, I would like to test many (at least $\omega(\text{poly}(|X|)$) random $z$.

Comment: Do you want an estimate dependent only on $d$, $k$, and $|X|$?  Or do you allow to take into account that $f$ is chosen randomly? In the first case, you can't say much of anything; in the second case, Dustin's comment is a good answer.

Comment: I definitely allow to take into account that $f$ is chosen randomly, at first. I would like to keep $f$ fixed for each test $z:=z_1,\ldots, z_i,\ldots \in \mathbb{R}^d$

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a long comment than an answer:

Let's assume $f$ is a $k\times d$ matrix with orthogonal rows, each with norm $\sqrt{d/k}$ (random $f$'s of this form are known to satisfy JL). Consider the function on the sphere $\sigma\colon S^{d-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\sigma(v)=\|f(v)\|$. This function is maximized at vectors in the rowspace of $f$, and minimized at vectors in the nullspace, and somewhere in between is the inverse image of $[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$. This can be viewed as a thickened version of $\sigma^{-1}(\{1\})$, which should be a $(d-2)$-dimensional algebraic variety.

Now draw $z$ at random (according to some distribution). We succeed if

$$v_x:=\frac{x-z}{\|x-z\|}\in \sigma^{-1}\big([1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]\big)\quad \forall x\in X.$$

Unfortunately, the $v_x$'s are dependent, so you should probably focus on $v_x$ for a single $x$, and then perform a union bound. To do this, you first need to define a distribution for $z$.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Well, we can assume $z$ to be drawn with normal gaussian distribution, i.e. each coordinate is drawn according to $N(0,1)$.

Comment: I added $N(0,1)$ hypothesis to the original question.